# How to detect differences between folders? (after copying) - on win 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, file-transfer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Compare directories on Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/102063/compare-directories-on-windows)

I copied many many files from one hard drive to another.
During the process some of the files where skipped.
I now want to find who they where and try to take care of them.

How can I figure out what files are missing from my copy ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Teracopy](http://www.codesector.com/teracopy.php) is excellent, and it can do that.

Also, it can verify that the files were correctly copied (checksum each end and compare).

It's also a all-around nice replacement/upgrade for the windows copy dialog.

Answer (score 3):

I ended using [PathSync](http://www.cockos.com/pathsync/)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using [TotalCommander](http://ghisler.com/) as your file manager, than there's a "Synchronize Dir..." command that will show you a visual comparison between two directory structures. It is very efficient, and much faster to use than traditional diff software.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Beyond Compare to do the comparison. http://www.scootersoftware.com/

To make the copy, try robocopy and keep a logfile. It gives clear output what has been skipped.

Answer (score 0):

I've had some success with Microsoft's Sync Toy, it doesn't cope very well with removable drives which are allocated a different drive letter each time they are connected but it might help you:

[Microsoft Sync Toy](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=c26efa36-98e0-4ee9-a7c5-98d0592d8c52&displaylang=en)

You would set up a sync partnership between the two different directories and then in theory running the Sync Toy would synchronise the two.

Answer (score 0):

I am using [SyncBack - Freeware](http://www.2brightsparks.com/downloads.html#freeware) from 2brightsparks.

When you start the program it pops up with the config for a new task. Select backup and the two folders you want to check. After clicking on run the program checks the differences and shows you a list of all the files. Afterwards you can decide if Syncback should copy the missing files.